# Are we able to track the Aging of Azure DevOps objects, such as Bugs, and Tasks?

Tags: azure-devops, reporting, azure-boards

For example, if a Bug's "Created Date" goes beyond 5 days, without the "state" changing, are we able to:

a) update another field e.g. Custom State = Requires Immediate Triage.

b) and/or send an email to a group, or individual.

c) and/or create a report that shows aging of all items for N number of days.

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 1):

This task requires custom scripts. As example, you can use [Azure Devops CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/?view=azure-devops):

1. Run [wiql query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/wiql-syntax?view=azure-devops) to get old bugs with `az boards query --wiql`. You can check the `System.CreatedDate` and `Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StateChangeDate` fields.
2. Update work item with `az boards work-item update`

Here you can find the sample script: https://github.com/ashamrai/AzureDevOpsExtensions/blob/master/CustomPSTasks/UpdateBugTargetDate.ps1

For reporting you can use [Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/data-connector-connect?view=azure-devops).